# Update configurable attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I need to update an attribute of a configurable:

```
$product = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )->load( 3268 );
$configurableAttributesData = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();
$product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes( true );
$configurableAttributesData[ 0 ][ 'values' ][ 0 ][ 'pricing_value' ] = abs( 17.99 - 32.00 );
$product->setConfigurableAttributesData( $configurableAttributesData );
$product->getResource()->save( $product );
```

It doesn't work, how do I update the configurable option?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should replace

```
$product->getResource()->save( $product );
```

with

```
$product->save();
```

since the magic of saving configurable attributes data happens in the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable` models save method which is called in the after save process of the product model.

Comment: Doesn't work I get this error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`staging_db`.`etpq_catalog_product_super_link`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ETPQ_CAT_PRD_SPR_LNK_PRD_ID_ETPQ_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `etpq_catalog_product_entity` (`enti)' in...

Comment: The code should work with my change, I've tested it in my environment with several products. The error you get is about an entry in table `catalog_product_super_link` with a nonexistent product_id. Do you have more code, espcially a call of `setConfigurableProductsData` in your code? Your data is trying to insert something into `catalog_product_super_link` with a wrong `product_id`. Anyway your posted code shouldn't do any changes to `catalog_product_super_link` table at all.